# repo forall hard reset tag issue

Tags: android, linux, git, github

I am not able to appreciate git reset hard concept because of following issue:

Consider the repository structure:

Android>A

A>B

A>C

A>D

(B,C,D are child branch of A and have .git in them)

in linux putty terminal I did this:

cd Android/A

cd C

C: git describe

Shows -> YesterdayTag  (that's ok, now I want to change every .git to "tagLatest"

cd ..

cd B

B: git describe

Shows -> YesterdayTag  (cool, now I want to change this and every other .git )

B: repo forall -c git reset --hard tagLatest

B: git describe

Shows--> tagLatest (correct this is what I expect!, however see below)

cd ..

cd C

C: git describe

still shows-> yesterDayTag , I expect repoforall to change every .git to "tagLatest"

Please let me know if you have any clue. Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

these are not branches that you are talking about. You have nested git repositories. You better have the tag across all repos if you want the reset to work.

Comment: thanks, doesn't repo forall mean -> update all .git in the entire tree?